# Function that returns a list of hexadecimal numbers (only hexadecimal digits)

Tags: python, function, return, hex

I want to create a function that returns a list of hexadecimal digits only.
But I don't know how to make it because when I tried to make it a hex function,
hex returns as str.
Does anyone know how to make this, can you make it and show it to me?

I've made numerous attempts and all have failed.
and I want a function that can return a list that can be stored in a variable like below.

```
[0x18, 0x82, 0x19, 0x89, 0x91, 0x71, 0x38, 0x58, 0x10, 0x47, 0x89, 0x65, 0x86, 0x75, 0x26, 0x58,
 0x66, 0x44, 0x74, 0x72, 0x47, 0x11, 0x13, 0x30, 0x46, 0x13, 0x58, 0x28, 0x81, 0x55, 0x61, 0x23]
```

Comment: I'll say it again. It's not returning something in another format that has that format, it's returning a list of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: There is no standard hexadecimal data type in Python. Hexadecimal numbers are merely integers. You can visualise an integer's hexadecimal equivalent with the built-in *hex* or *format* functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why has no one advised this code?

```
def make_key(text : str = None) :
    if text == None :
        raise ValueError("Untyped variable: 'text'")
    return [int(hex(ord(s)), 16) for s in text]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Fred explained:
Python can't really handle hex values. They are handeled as integers, and if you want to print them in a hex format, you can use the `hex()` function, like so:

```
def return_something():
    return [0x18, 0x82, 0x19, 0x89, 0x91, 0x71, 0x38, 0x58, 0x10, 0x47, 0x89, 0x65, 0x86, 0x75, 0x26, 0x58,
 0x66, 0x44, 0x74, 0x72, 0x47, 0x11, 0x13, 0x30, 0x46, 0x13, 0x58, 0x28, 0x81, 0x55, 0x61, 0x23]

data = return_something()
for i in data:
    print(hex(i))
```

Than the output will be:

```
0x18
0x82
0x19
...
```